# how can i fix this syntax error in QBASIC about READ DATA

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, qbasic, read-data

This is my code

```
INPUT "what year right now : ", thn1
CLS
thn2 = thn1
num = 0
PRINT "No      Jenis Kelamin     Tanggal Lahir     NPM         Nama"
10 READ jk$, tgl$, thl, npm$, nma$
IF jk$ = "0" THEN END
thn1 = thn2
thn1 = thn1 - thl
IF jk$ = "L" OR thn1 < 18 THEN GOTO 10
num = num + 1
PRINT num, jk$, tgl$, npm$, nma$
GOTO 10
DATA "L","11-03-2000",2000,"52418436","Fajar","P","20-06-1999",1999,"89436754","Rida","P","17-01-2002",2001,"37904638","Selly","L","09-08-1998",1998,"47382901","Fadli","P","28-04-2000",2000,"37464903","Bella","0","0","0","0","0","0"
```

the output is just as i wanted but there is popup alert :

Unhandled Error #2

Line 6(in main module)
Syntax error
continue?

Yes No

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are attempting to read `"0"` (type `STRING`) into variable `thl` (default type is `SINGLE`) when the last `READ` occurs (you also need to remove the last `"0"`). Change

```
"Bella","0","0","0","0","0","0"
```

to

```
"Bella","0","0",0,"0","0"
```

You can also use multiple `DATA` statements to keep things organized.  Here is how I might write the code, assuming memory is not an issue:

```
DATA "L","11-03-2000",2000,"52418436","Fajar"
DATA "P","20-06-1999",1999,"89436754","Rida"
DATA "P","17-01-2002",2001,"37904638","Selly"
DATA "L","09-08-1998",1998,"47382901","Fadli"
DATA "P","28-04-2000",2000,"37464903","Bella"
DATA "0","00-00-0000",0000,"00000000","00000"
```